# Create a TRIGGER with PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers, database-trigger

I would like to create my first trigger on my `PostgreSQL` database but I got a `syntax error`.

The trigger should be able to delete each row from `token_jwt_usertoken` table where `date_information` is inferior than `now() - interval '2 month'`. In other words, if the row is expired from at least 2 months, the row should be deleted.

This is my command :

```
CREATE FUNCTION after_update_token() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $after_update_token$


BEGIN
    IF old.date_information < now() - INTERVAL '2 month'
      THEN
        DELETE FROM token_jwt_usertoken WHERE old.date_information < now() - INTERVAL '2 month';
    END IF;
END;

$after_update_token$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER after_update_token AFTER UPDATE ON token_jwt_usertoken FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE FUNCTION after_update_token();
```

I get :

> [2019-02-07 17:14:01] [42601] ERROR: syntax error at or near
>   "FUNCTION" [2019-02-07 17:14:01] Position : 92

Then, I don't know if my request is well-written in my trigger.

Thank you !

Comment: The trigger function and the `TRIGGER` itself are separately-created objects. See the [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html#PLPGSQL-TRIGGER-EXAMPLE) for examples.

Comment: you're missing `when` clause

Comment: In PostgreSQL you have to create a function or procedure and call it. There is no `BEGIN` allowed in the command.

Comment: @NickBarnes I edited my question but I have a syntax issue yet.

Comment: You've typed `FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE FUNCTION` but I think the correct syntax is `FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE`.

Comment: @lau: Yes, that's it. Both will work in Postgres 11, but older versions only accept `EXECUTE PROCEDURE`.

Comment: I didn't even know it changed on version 11. It's just that the one `FUNCTION` matching `Position : 92` is the latter one, not the one in `CREATE FUNCTION`

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have to declare a function and call that like they say:

```
CREATE [ CONSTRAINT ] TRIGGER name { BEFORE | AFTER | INSTEAD OF } { event [ OR ... ] }
    ON table
    [ FROM referenced_table_name ]
    [ NOT DEFERRABLE | [ DEFERRABLE ] { INITIALLY IMMEDIATE | INITIALLY DEFERRED } ]
    [ FOR [ EACH ] { ROW | STATEMENT } ]
    [ WHEN ( condition ) ]
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE function_name ( arguments )

where event can be one of:

    INSERT
    UPDATE [ OF column_name [, ... ] ]
    DELETE
    TRUNCATE
```

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/sql-createtrigger.html

Answer (score 0):

According to @lau answer, this is the code which solve my issue :

```
CREATE FUNCTION after_update_token() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $after_update_token$
  BEGIN
    IF to_timestamp(old.date_information, 'YYYY/MM/DD') < now() - INTERVAL '2 month'
      THEN
        DELETE FROM token_jwt_usertoken WHERE to_timestamp(old.date_information, 'YYYY/MM/DD') < now() - INTERVAL '2 months';
    END IF;
END;

$after_update_token$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER after_update_token AFTER UPDATE ON token_jwt_usertoken FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE after_update_token();
```

I had to write : `FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE` instead of `FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE FUNCTION`